# What are these "extra" punctuations on my keyboard and how to use them

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I have a lenovo X220 computer and there are these extra punctuations on my keyboard.

[image: Lenovo X220 Keyboard]

So I have circled out all these extra punctuations and numbers that I have no idea what they are and how to use them; can someone please explain what they are and how to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the numpad. Typically the numbers will have the same color as the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key so it'll be quite easy to recognize how to type it. In this case it was a bit strange

> On some laptop computers, the Num Lock key is used to convert part of the main keyboard to act as a (slightly skewed) numeric keypad rather than letters
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Num_lock

To type those numbers in **normal mode** (i.e Numlock OFF) you'll need to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd>. If you don't want to keep holding it you can toggle NumLock (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>NumLk</kbd> in your case) and now the function of those keys will be reversed: to type the normal characters on those numpad keys you need to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

That's the numberpad, as you would see on the right side of a regular keyboard.  You would hit (at the same time) the blue function key on the bottom left (this activates the buttons with the blue text) and the <kbd>Scroll lock</kbd> button above the <kbd>F11</kbd> key.