# How to type the Euro Symbol € on US English keyboard in Windows 10 without a numpad or "AltGr" key?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, unicode, input, symbols

There are already many questions about typing the € symbol on keyboards where it is not one of the keycaps.

Unless I have missed one of them, the answers fall into several categories:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, which works on European keyboard layouts, maybe even UK English layouts, but not the US English layout.
2. Pressing the  <kbd>AltGr</kbd>  key together with some key, usually also  <kbd>E</kbd>  from memory.
3. Holding down the  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  key, then typing the Unicode hexadecimal codepoint for the symbol on the numeric keypad while holding the  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  key, and then releasing it.

But

1. won't work because in Australia we use the US English layout and there are no symbols mapped to any Alt-key combinations.
2. won't work because my HP ProBook 430 came with a US keyboard, and US keyboards have no  <kbd>AltGr</kbd>  key.
3. won't work because the HP ProBook 430 is a nice small portable size and doesn't have a numeric keypad.

Yes I can install a different keyboard layout, but those move around many symbols programmers use and I'm a touch-typist so it would slow me down considerably.

Is there no other method I've missed among the other answers? Will I have to stick to cut-and-pasting the € symbol in Windows?

Comment: “US keyboards have no "Alt Gr" key” Oh, but they do. It’s the right Alt key.

Comment: On Windows Alt Gr can be emulated via Ctrl+ Alt - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#Control_+_Alt_as_a_substitute

Comment: @DanielB: I have owned laptops with an altgr key before and I also switch to foreign layouts where the right alt works as altgr, so I know that's where it ought to work and maybe does under some circumstances, but when I hit the right alt and the e on this machine I get this... well the Google Chrome settings context menu pops up! So I tried Notepad and right-alt E causes the "Edit" menu to pop up.

Comment: @hippietrail: It's really just a matter of OS-level keyboard layouts. There is no distinct scancode for AltGr on PC keyboards, so it is literally the same as "right Alt".

Comment: @Robert: Yes I thought there was a substitute for Alt Gr involving Ctrl + Alt, but any combination I try along the lines of Ctrl + Alt + E does not result in entering a Euro symbol, unless there is one specific one I have not found and tried )-:

Comment: It might be easier to use software that remaps the keys to whatever you want. I use Karabiner on Mac for these purposes.

Comment: @DanielB only in the [US International layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#US-International). The standard US QWERTY layout is far more common and has no AltGr or dead keys

Comment: @phuclv I was referring to the physical keyboard. It’s not entirely obvious that the right Alt key is not the same as the left Alt key if they both have the same label.

Comment: On a *UK* keyboard it would be <AltGr>+**4** (a.k.a. <RAlt>+**4**), where that's the 4 on the number row. <Shift>+4 gives a dollar sign as I believe it does in US layouts.  So it's worth trying <RAlt>+ all the number keys

Comment: This might not apply to your situation (so hence, not an answer) BUT: many 
 text editors for european languages will autocorrect (e) to the euro sign. So, you could change the language to UK english, if you are typing it into a text editor, such as word.

Comment: Regarding "Alt E , which works on European keyboards, maybe even British, but not US." - 1. Alt+e opens the active program's Edit menu in almost all situations. 2. there's no single "European keyboard" layout. 3. My Spanish keyboard has AltGr+e as the € symbol, and my UK keyboard has € on AltGr+4

Comment: It's not Alt+E, it's Ctrl+Alt+E. It's just that right alt happens to be Ctrl+Alt, so right alt + E gives you €, while left alt + E gives you nothing (since alt + key isn't supposed to "type" anything). "Alt Gr" is a common label on some non-US keyboards, but the only distinction is left vs. right alt, where some US physical keyboards use the same scancode for both, so they're indistinguishable. Windows allows you to use Ctrl + Alt to simulate a right alt press, which is equivalent to "Alt Gr". Keyboard layouts do not affect this, it's all about the scancodes from the physical keyboard.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Looking for a picture of an HP ProBook 430 which showed a keyboard large enough to read the keys well, I found this image: [image: https://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/Notebooks/HP/ProBook_430-G1/ttastatur.jpg]

It shows an <kbd>Fn</kbd> key between the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (actually called <kbd>Strg</kbd> in this picture, since the picture shows a German version) and the Start ("Windows" logo) key.  Hold that down, and then the picture shown indicates <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd> correspond to Numpad <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, and <kbd>7</kbd>.  So, there is a way to use a Numpad by holding down <kbd>Fn</kbd>.

Try holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing 0128 on the numpad.  So, to do that on this computer, hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd>, and press <kbd>M</kbd>.  Then, release <kbd>Fn</kbd> and hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd> again, and press <kbd>J</kbd>.  Then, release <kbd>Fn</kbd> and hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd> again, and press <kbd>K</kbd>.  Then, release <kbd>Fn</kbd>, and hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd> again, and press <kbd>8</kbd>.  Then release <kbd>Fn</kbd>.  Finally, release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.  (Yes, you should hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> down the entire time.)

If that works well, you may wish to try again by just holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, holding <kbd>Fn</kbd>, and typing <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> (without needing to keep releasing <kbd>Fn</kbd>), and then just release <kbd>Fn</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> in the end.

Comment: Well just using Fn with the letter keys did not cause numbers to be entered so I was not hopeful, but trying both the more complex and less complex sequences of keys actually did work! ALT+FN together then MJK8 then relase ALT+FN: €

Comment: That's the numpad on laptops without a numpad on the right. See [What are these “extra” punctuations on my keyboard and how to use them](https://superuser.com/q/1259240/241386). There'll also be a numlock button if the laptop has such a numpad (in this case it's in the same key as "rollen" so just press `Fn+rollen`) which after activated inverts the keys' behavior and allows you to press the numbers without Fn. Unfortunately a few new laptops lines drop the numpad completely

Comment: "foreign language version" - the picture shows a German keyboard. "Strg" abbreviates "Steuerung", which is exactly the German word for "control".

Comment: There's no reason to release the [Fn] key. Its a modifier key like Shift or Ctrl, not an "action" key that dictates the beginning or end of a command.

Comment: Not all laptops have the “replacement numpad” in this style; for example, mine does not. Which is certainly obnoxious, but true

Answer (score 65):

**Yes there is!**

You can find all kinds of symbols, including the euro symbol, on the **Emoji picker**.

1. Go to where you want to enter the symbol
2. Hit <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> on your keyboard
3. Navigate to the *Symbols* tab (Ω)
4. Navigate to the *Currency Symbols* tab ($)
5. And select the euro symbol. (you might have to scroll once)

This should work in every application accepting keyboard input. After doing this a few times the symbol will show up under "Most Recently Used" as well.

Note that the symbol tab got added in version 1903; if you only get the emojis, consider updating.

Comment: after pressing `Win+.` or `Win+;` just type the name of the symbol to look for. Unfortunately somehow it works only for emojis

Comment: @MMM I'm an insider and always use the pre-release versions so I've used that for years. What I meant is that you can't switch to the symbol and kaomoji tab by keyboard, and the search feature also doesn't work for symbols

Comment: This solution works for any Windows 10 computer with a keyboard, while the accepted one is only valid for a certain kind of laptop.

Answer (score 24):

I use AutoHotKey for this. You can use it for endless customisation but I started using it mainly to get the € and £ symbols on a US keyboard.

https://www.autohotkey.com/

Just create a script with the following, set it to run at startup (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, `shell:startup`, drop a link to your script in there), and you can then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to get the €. You can remap this to whatever you like, that's just what I picked as that's where the `$` is. You can put it on E or whatever if you prefer.

```
#SingleInstance force

^+4::
   Send, €
Return
```

It does require additional software but it's easier than the other methods IMO, and if you get into AutoHotKey you may end up using it to create all sorts of other shortcuts, it's very powerful.

Comment: This is actually what could be most useful, since it can basically replace any key combination. Good find. It's also better than the picked answer because remembering an arbitrary number combination every time I want to use €, ß, ½ or some other symbol is really hard but just putting it on the space where you're used to it is just muscle memory.

Comment: If you use this approach, make sure you copy and paste the code.  If you type it out, you are back to the original problem of typing the Euro symbol.  By the way, I am using a Windows 10 desktop with what I think is a US keyboard.  By the way, some of the keyboard combinations are software dependent.  For example, Alt-Ctrl-e works in Wordpad, but not in Notepad and not in an html textarea.  Alt-0128 seems to work everywhere.

Comment: +1 for an AHK solution. Another option is to open up a modal box when pushing shift 4, with options on which variant you want, this can save you from having lots of  key combinations being taken up.

```InputBox, SingleKey, Choose Currency Symbol, $(1) `€(2) `£(3)
 if(SingleKey = 1)
 {
  Send, $
 }
 else if(SingleKey = 2)
 {
  Send, €
 }
 else if(SingleKey = 3)
 {
  Send, £
 }```

Comment: @DanBracuk Alt-Ctrl-e is a Microsoft Word specific shortcut. Alt-0128 will work anywhere but the 0128 HAS to be entered specifically on the numeric keypad, you can't do Alt-0128 on the number row. Most laptops don't have numeric keypads, hence the problem. AHK will work system-wide in every app.

Comment: @DanBracuk You don't really have to type in the euro symbol, you can search for it online and copy paste it into the config file.

Comment: The syntax in AutoHotKey 2 has changed. The following will work now:

#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

<^>!e::Send "€"

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried activating the international English keyboard layout?

It's <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> on this keyboard:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/windows-keyboard-layouts#

select  "United States-International"

Comment: I would write "installing" the international layout rather than "activating". I forgot what I didn't like about it but it's all flooding back. " and ' are dead keys. I like them on Spanish layouts but when they do double duty as dead-diaeresis/double quote and dead-acute/apostrophe/single quote you press either key once you get nothing and when you press it twice you get two of the same character. This is a nightmare for a coder. I could install normal US and international US and switch every time I need to type € but I'm not convinced that's any better than TOOGAM's solution...

Comment: Then your only hope is Alt+numpad, or building yourself a custom keyboard map with [MSKLC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) (I use one for french to have access to upper case accented letters; it works with W10)

Comment: The question says there is no AltGr on the machine in question.

Comment: @Lightness Races with Monica: With the layout set to US-International, the right Alt key usually functions as AltGr. If it doesn't, or if there's no right Alt, Windows will interpret Ctrl+Alt as AltGr

Comment: typing with the US International keyboard is a nightmare due to the dead keys. And it'll also interferes with a lot of keyboard shortcuts because AltGr is converted to Ctrl+Alt so things like Ctrl+Alt+E will not work

Comment: @hippietrail You can also type ` (or any other dead key for the matter) plus the space key to get one of that character. I'm already used to the Spanish layout, but I can understand that people used to having a dedicated key for the back tick will find it weird to have to press two keys to get the usual ` character.

Comment: @hippietrail Swapping the International keyboard is easy in Windows 10.  `Win` + `Spacebar` lets you swap keyboards you have activate.  Usually, I type with the English-US keyboard and swap to English-International when I need accents or symbols.

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Run) and then enter `charmap` and enter.

[image: Character map]

Answer (score 7):

Someone else suggested autohotkey, but I think it's worth mentioning the excellent [WinCompose](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose/) project, that gives you full <kbd>compose-key</kbd> functionality (e.g. I can type <kbd>compose</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> or <kbd>compose</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to get € (it's a little like a C with an = on top of it, after all, or an E with an =)) on Windows. It provides a much easier to use (in my opinion) interface than autohotkey; it's just the traditional .XCompose file (which can, of course, be edited to your liking to add whatever compose sequences you like). Plus it comes preloaded with all the basic compose sequences.

You can map the compose key to a number of different keys on the keyboard that don't see much use. I have mine mapped to the windows key, since I don't use the shortcuts on that key and it's a convenient location, but you can also map it to things like scroll lock or pause/break that I'm pretty sure no one has ever pressed since before the 90s.

I have no affiliation with the wincompose project, I just like it a lot and think more people should know it exists.

Comment: I use WinCompose *all* the time. It's modeled after the Compose functionality which is standard on Linux systems. What I like about it is that the sequences are intuitive enough that I can usually guess what I need to type without having to look it up. For example `compose ^ letter` will generate the letter with a circumflex accent, `compose " letter` will generate the letter with an umlaut.

Comment: Yeah, I use it too - with a hack so that I can type Compose-u-e to get ü (I'm in Germany, and "ue" is the canonical way to represent ü if you don't have umlauts (eg) because you are using an Enigma machine.

Comment: Thanks for spreading the word! Note that though WinCompose was initially an AutoHotKey project, for numerous reasons I rewrote it in C# in 2014.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your keyboard layout, there might be an <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key on the on-screen keyboard. Type **osk** into the search box on the taskbar and then choose "On-Screen Keyboard" from the choices that appear.

With <kbd>AltGr</kbd> pressed, the € symbol appears in the top row for me (UK keyboard layout) but not sure where it would appear in other layouts.

[image: The Windows on-screen keyboard with the keys in a dark grey colour. The <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key and the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key are both highlighted in blue. In the top row, the € symbol is visible]

Comment: Yes I was using the on-screen keyboard even before I posted the question and nothing caused any extra symbols to show up from the US English keyboard layout as in this image.

Comment: the onscreen keyboard shows exactly which keys are available in the current layout, so it doesn't help you type the character if the layout doesn't have that character

Answer (score 3):

I use Windows 8 but I'm assuming that Windows 10 has the same (don't have access to a Windows 10 computer at the moment to be able to check).

Go into the start menu and there should be an app called Character Map where you can select a font and get a list of all the accented characters, special characters, etc that are available for the selected font

Answer (score 2):

€ - I got that by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> - my keyboard is either English or Spanish - it has the ñ, so it must be Spanish. I don't know if the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> combination will work for you though.

Comment: I have an English keyboard, and CTRL-ALT-E gives me this: é

Comment: @Jimmery: On Windows? Mine gives me nothing at all for CTRL+ALT+E.

Comment: Windows interprets Ctrl+Alt as AltGr in some settings, such as US-International, and apparently also in Spanish.

Comment: I have an English keyboard, and Ctrl+Alt+4 gives me this: €

Comment: @rchard2scout `AltGr` is **always** converted to `Ctrl+Alt` on Windows so they're equivalent. [Can I make Ctrl+Alt NOT act like AltGr on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/592970/241386) The answer is NO

Comment: To avoid an endless back and forth in the comments here, please note that there is no single "English keyboard" in Windows, but many, such as "English US", "English US International", "English UK". Each of these has symbols in different places, so without specifying which you're using, any details are going to be next to useless to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Some software allows you to input any Unicode characters directly. For example in Libre Office, Word and Wordpad just type the code point followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. So for the Euro € symbol **type 20ac then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>**

Alternatively you can install the [Unicode IME](https://web.archive.org/web/20110709014227/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/05/18/419117.aspx) which allows you to type any Unicode characters in any applications

Some other ways can be found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign#Entry_methods

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the [**Quick Accent utility**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/quick-accent) in the official [Microsoft PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) tool.  Just hold down E and quickly click the space bar thrice.

[image: PowerToys Quick Accent video capture]